# What colors should be preferred for clothes of a person when the aim is to put the person in the picture just for creating a point of interest?

Tags: composition

This is *not* about portraits.

This is about scenes such as landscape where we put a human to create a point of interest. This is about scenes where I have to show the beauty of a garden, and for a point of interest I place a child playing with mud.

For these kind of scenes where person is not the subject, what kind of clothes colors should be preferred such that clothes do not distract attention?

I mean how do I decide the colors and color combinations of clothes?
What design patterns should be preferred (if having solid colors is not a choice)?
If having solid colors is a choice, then how should I decide what colors to prefer?

These are the kinds of scenes I am talking about:
https://500px.com/photo/211944061/passion-for-life-by-sona-moayedzadeh
https://500px.com/photo/187248643/alone-by-sona-moayedzadeh
https://500px.com/photo/181556019/man-with-dog-in-autumn-nature-by-jarom%C3%ADr-chalabala

I request example photos in answers.

Comment: This is, IMO, really too vague, too broad a question to answer here.  I would also suggest that the point of interest in a landscape ought to be the landscape itself.  Almost by definition a scene where a significant subject in it is a person will become a portrait.

Comment: you want to insert a person into the picture to create a point of interest, but you don't want that person to become the focal point of the photograph? I'm I understanding correctly? Or what do you mean by "...such that clothes do not distract attention"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is totally subjective, but I will give some ideas to explore and make your own choices.

First of all, **it is really hard for a person standing on a landscape not to be the point of interest**, because human brains are wired to see people in the first place. It really does not matter how tiny the person is.[image]
http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/1x/Fallen-Leaves-Autumn-Fall-Colorful-Walking-Man-1812180.jpg

So we have two basic options.

1. To integrate and blend the subject using a similar tone of the surrounding area.
   [image]
   https://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5287/5209704050_a3645af12d_b.jpg

You could cast an overall unsaturated style to blend the subject more.

[image]
http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/static/photo/1x/White-Dress-Landscape-Sexy-Woman-Dream-408471.jpg

2. Or to contrast them, specifically hue contrast.

[image]
https://static.pexels.com/photos/160562/girl-dress-red-plain-160562.jpeg

Comment: In all three of your examples the people at close to a "rule of thirds" guideline and the eye is drawn to them, not the landscape.  In the red dress shot the background is actually blurred so that the person stands out even more - this really makes all of them portraits, not landscapes.  As you say, it's very difficult to make a landscape with isolated people in them.  People almost have to be the landscape (like a crowd) to make them "blend in", and even then we're typically inclined to be drawn to individuals in a shot.

Comment: You could crop the images if you want. It requires time to find a photo of a person on a landscape that is not on a focus point.